# Finding more indices in a list close to zero

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of values, which represents a damping function when this is plotted (so a form of a sinusoide). This function passes the y=0 thus several times until it levels out on y=0. I need to find the index at the moment when the function passes zero for the third time.

All values are floats, so I have a function that finds the index closest to zero:

```py
def find_index(list_, value):
    array = np.asarray(list_)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return idx
```

Where 'list_' is the list and 'value' is zero.

This function does work, but it can only retrieve the index of the first moment the damping function (and thus the list) is closest to zero. Meaning that it will show an index of zero (because the damping function starts at zero). However, I need the index of the third time when it is closest to zero.

How can I obtain the index of the third time it will be closest to zero, instead of the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a change in the sign.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([10.0, 1.0, -1.0, -2.0, 1.0, 4.0])

y = np.sign(x) # -1 or 1

print(y)

>>> [ 1.  1. -1. -1.  1.  1.]
```

If you calculate the difference between consecutive elements using `np.diff` it will be either -2 or 2, both are boolean True.

```
>>> [ 0. -2.  0.  2.  0.]
```

Now get the indices of them using `np.nonzero`, which returns a tuple for each dimension. Pick the first one.

```
idx = np.nonzero(np.diff(y))[0]

print(idx)

>>> [1 3]
```